# bootstrap popup css not applying in for IE8

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-8, themes

I have implement bootstrap popup on site. It works fine in all browser except IE8,IE9. css not applying to page.

Comment: Any CSS and HTML? And does IE8/9 supports HTML5?

Answer (score 1):

Look at http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/
The "Internet Explorer 8 and 9" section